# json_object_to_json_string returns value WITHOUT quotes in 'c'

Tags: c, json, regex, mongodb, gcc

I am attempting something that should be simple.  I want to capture a value from a Mongo returned JSON and verify the value is what I am expecting.  To do this I am using json_object_to_json_string to return a string value of the json output.

The problem is the string is being returned with double-quotes surrounding the value:  EX "562416504bacd3940b8b2d5c" is returned instead of 562416504bacd3940b8b2d5c.

This then prevents me from being able to do a simple if match (see below).

Is there anyway to get the json value without the annoying double-quotes?

```
struct json_object *new_obj;

// Fetch document
while (mongoc_cursor_next (cursor, &doc)) 
{
char *docAsJSON = bson_as_json (doc, NULL);

// Grab account_id from session table
new_obj = json_tokener_parse(docAsJSON);
new_obj = json_object_object_get(new_obj, "account_id");
char * account_id_fromSession = json_object_to_json_string(new_obj);

if (strcmp(account_id,account_id_fromSession) == 0)
    {
    printf("\nids are the same\n\n");
    }
else
    {
    printf("\nids are NOT the same %s %s\n\n",account_id,account_id_fromSession);
    }
```

Output of code:

```
ids are NOT the same 562416504bacd3940b8b2d5c "562416504bacd3940b8b2d5c"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a "ghetto" solution, but would like something more elegant than a string substitution

```
void remove_all_chars(char* str, char c) 
{
char *pr = str, *pw = str;
while (*pr) 
    {
    *pw = *pr++;
    pw += (*pw != c);
    }
*pw = '\0';
}

// Remove " from token
remove_all_chars(account_id_fromSession, '"');
```

Thanks to @dasblinkenlight via another question for this code

Answer (score 4):

instead of `json_object_to_json_string()` which is like JSON stringify(), use `json_object_get_string()` which returns the string.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It has the additional benefit of not leaving escape characters when passing things like http or tcp addresses. I just spent 2 hours trying to figure out why my socket wasn't being initialized - I was trying to open a socket @ `"tcp:\/\/*:5555"` (should be `tcp://*:5555`). :D